# Quitar la coma en un double. Android studio

Tags: java, android

La cosa es que hago cálculos con decimales por lo que uso "double" para almacenar las cantidades. Y aunque el número sea entero sin decimales siempre me marca el .0 . Es decir , si el resultado es 40, me marca 40.0

Hay manera de quitar el decimal cuando el numero no tenga decimales reales?
Que si es 15.5 salga tal cual pero si es 50 no salga 50.0

Comment: Si quieres más precisión en los cálculos te recomiendo usar Bigdecimal antes de Double que no es del todo preciso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes extraer la partes entera y decimal con lo siguiente

```
double numero = 12345.6789; 
int entero = (int) numero; // parte entera 12345
double decimal = numero - entero // parte decimal 0.6789
```

Puedes usar la siguiente función que si el numero acaba con parte decimal 0 pues muestra como entero

```
public static String parse(double num) {
    if((int) num == num) return Integer.toString((int) num); StackOverflowException
    return String.valueOf(num); 
}
```

Otra manera más limpia sin recurrir a que salte un error

```
public static String mostrarNumero(double d) {
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
}
```

De forma más compacta

```
public static String mostrarNumero(double d) {
    return (d == (long) d) ? string.format("%d",(long)d):String.format("%s",d);
}
```

Si tienes los siguientes números:

```
232.00000000
0.18000000000
1237875192.0
4.5800000000
0.00000000
1.23450000
```

Se mostrarán

```
232
0.18
1237875192
4.58
0
1.2345
```

Extraído de varias respuestas [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: genial mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, La forma en la que prefiero formatear es usando `DecimalFormat` como sigue:

```
double a = -212.2345645;

// para Java
System.out.println (new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(a));

// para Android
txtTextField.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(a));
```

debes importar:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Los resultados para:

```
212.2345645
212
212.1
-123
-212.5645
```

son:

```
212.23
212
212.1
-123
-212.56
```

Comment: Genial. Mil gracias